# How to pass Command Line arguments in Robot framework to make it available for all libraries?

Tags: python, robotframework

I have developed few libraries for robot framework for my feature testing, for these libraries all variables are coming from a variables.py file. Below is the code block for variables.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import os
import optparse
import HostProperties
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from robot.api import logger

testBed = 748
tree = ET.parse('/home/p6mishra/mybkp/testLibs/TestBedProperties.xml')

class raftGetTestBedProp(object):
  def GetTestBedNumber(self):
    _attributeDict = {}
    root = tree.getroot()
    for _tbProperties in root:
        for _tbNumber in _tbProperties:
            get_tb = _tbNumber.attrib
            if get_tb['name']== str(testBed):
                get_tb2 = _tbNumber.attrib
                return root, get_tb2['name']


  def GetTestBedProperties(self, root, testBedNumber):
    propertyList = []
    for _tbProperties in root:
        get_tb = _tbProperties.attrib
        for _tbProperty in _tbProperties:
            get_tb1 = _tbProperty.attrib
            if get_tb1['name']== str(testBedNumber):
              for _tbPropertyVal in _tbProperty:
                get_tb2 = _tbPropertyVal.attrib
                if 'name' in get_tb2.keys():
                    propertyList.append(get_tb2['name'])
    return propertyList


  def GetIPNodeType(self, root, testBedNumber):
    for tbNumber1 in root.findall('tbproperties'):
      for tbNumber in tbNumber1:
        ipv4support = tbNumber.find('ipv4support').text
        ipv6support = tbNumber.find('ipv6support').text
        lbSetup = tbNumber.find('lbSetup').text
        name = tbNumber.get('name')
        if name==str(testBedNumber):
            return ipv4support, ipv6support, lbSetup



obj1, obj2 = raftGetTestBedProp().GetTestBedNumber()
ipv4support, ipv6support, lbSetup = raftGetTestBedProp().GetIPNodeType(obj1, obj2)
AlltestBedProperties = raftGetTestBedProp().GetTestBedProperties(obj1, obj2)

HostPropertyDict = {}
for testBedProperty in AlltestBedProperties:
    try:
        val1 = getattr(HostProperties, testBedProperty)
        HostPropertyDict[testBedProperty] = val1
    except:
        logger.write("Error in the Configuration data. Please correct and then proceed with the testing", 'ERROR')


for indexVal in range(len(AlltestBedProperties)):
    temp  = AlltestBedProperties[indexVal]
    globals()[temp] = HostPropertyDict[temp]
```

This variables.py file returns all variables defined in HostProperties.py file based on testbed number. 
If i import this library like `from variables import *` in other libraries it gives me the required variables.

But the problem is here I have hardcoaded 748 so it works fine for me but i want to pass this testbed number information from `pybot command` and make it available for my Robot testcase as well as all the developed libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you post Robot Framework code you use to call these Python files? I think you could use *pybot -v testBed:748* and pass it as a parameter to __init__ your class. I am not sure without seeing how you start your Python variables.

A bit different way is to use environment variables:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import os
import optparse
import HostProperties
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from robot.api import logger

testBed = os.environ['testbed']
tree = ET.parse('/home/p6mishra/mybkp/testLibs/TestBedProperties.xml')
```

Before starting pybot just define this environment parameter:

```
export testbed=748
pybot tests.txt
```